# laravel eloquent multiple record hasMany

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

```
        return Store::whereRaw('status = 1 AND ' . 'pay_status = 1 AND ' . $conditions[0])
        ->storeBooks()
        ->whereRaw('status = 1 AND ' . $conditions[1])
        ->search($request->input('search'), null, true)
        ->simplePaginate(20)
        ->makeHidden(['description', 'publisher', 'edition', 'mobile', 'cat_title', 'city_name']);
```

Hi, I have an store table and this table has some book in store_books table.
i want to search in store books where store has status 1.
I wrote above code but not work.
anyone can help me? Please!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

> In your Store model

```
public function books()
{
  return $this->hasMany("App\StoreBooks",'store_id');
}
```

> In your controller's function

```
$results = [];
$stores = Store::where('status',1)->get();

foreach($stores as $store)
{
  $books = $stores->books;
  foreach($books as $book)
  {
    $results[] = $book;
  }
}

return $results;
```

Comment: I want catch the StoreBook model items

Comment: Means you want to search all store_books where status of store is 1 ?

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i want search in all of store books. How can I do that?

Comment: It will give to the all the store books which store id = 1, now what you want . please explain?

Comment: I want to search in all of the store books but the all of them will not return to me.